# Android Error:(9, 36) error: code too large

Tags: android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter, android-largeheap

I am using huge Multidimensional: [image] Data array in a Java file and giving me an error Error:(9, 36) error: code too large.. And it's not compiling.

Data is like this:

```
     String[][] Searchitems = new String[][]{
        {"Maruti","1", "Swift", "1", "vdi","1"},
        {"Maruti","1", "Swift", "1", "vdi","2"},
        {"Maruti","1", "Swift", "2", "vdi","3"},
        {"Maruti","2", "Swift", "2", "vdi","4"},
        {"Maruti","2", "Swift", "3", "vdi","5"},
        {"Maruti","2", "Swift", "3", "vdi","6"},
        {"Maruti","2", "Swift", "4", "vdi","7"},
        {"Maruti","3", "Swift", "4", "vdi","8"},
        {"Maruti","3", "Swift", "5", "vdi","9"},
        {"Maruti","3", "Swift", "5", "vdi","10"}
};
```

Comment: did you tried keeping this data in strings.xml file

Comment: Will you provide any sample that how can i use multidimensional array in string.xml

 <array name="apptour">
        <item>@drawable/a</item>
        <item>@drawable/b</item>
</array >

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407912/code-too-large-compilation-error-in-java

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377004/how-to-retrieve-2d-array-from-xml-string-resource-for-android

Comment: Any other solution